# change login time/date on Linux

Tags: authentication, linux, timestamp

Is it possible to 'backdate' a login time on a Linux server by changing the date?  For example, I just ran `lastlog` on one of my servers and included in the expected records was this:

```
root                                       Wed Dec 31 16:00:10 -0800 1969
daemon                                     **Never logged in**
bin                                        **Never logged in**
```

I'm guessing that lastlog for root has something to do with the original system setup, but it left me wondering, could a user roll back the date, log in, then correct the date to make it look like they hadn't logged in recently?

Comment: ... except for the login in which they rolled back the date ...

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the posted date is exactly 1 second prior to epoch time minimum value, which is often stored as a decimal number as 0, I imagine the root login you're seeing is actually stored as a value -1.  I'm not sure why it is stored that way instead of "**Never logged in**", though.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time